# ImageView and UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I would like to create a button with a custom image ( background image), i have done this.
how  can assign the imageview to may button ?

thanks for your answers

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(goToGeoloc)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(245.0, 8.0, 45.0, 45.0);
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ico_plan.png"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@izan you dont need a separate `UIImageView` to show on the `UIButton`.

A `UIButton` comes with 2 `UIImageView` inside it. you can just set the image for these 2 imageViews.

You can set the image for the first imageview using `setImage:forState:` method. By doing this you cannot show any title for that button. If you want to show title as well as image on the button you should use `setBackgroundImage:forState:` method.

Answer (score 7):

What you want is:

```
[button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

or

```
[button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Whta is the diferrence between setBackground and setImage ??

Comment: this is 2015 ... Google and StackOverflow are replacing documentation.

Answer (score 5):

Use the setImage method;

```
- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state
```

So your code would be;

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(goToGeoloc) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(245.0, 8.0, 45.0, 45.0);

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ico_plan.png"];
[button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Or I you still want your text to be shown use;

```
- (void)setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state
```

Which would result in;

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(goToGeoloc) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(245.0, 8.0, 45.0, 45.0);

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ico_plan.png"];
[button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

UIButton documentation;
http://bit.ly/kruq5y

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(goToGeoloc)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ico_plan.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(245.0, 8.0, 45.0, 45.0);
```

Hope this helps